# There is no menu to create "new team project" on visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

After updating visual studio 2019 to version 16.2.2 when I wanted to create a new team project on my collection, it missed this menu item.
Everything works ok and I can create it from web portal but There is no menu item,its just a menu to manage connection, whats wrong?Is it a bug or what happened to it?

[image]

It must be something like this photo:

[image]

Comment: I have this also in 2019, which version of 2019 do you use?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk VS Enterprise and TFS Express Edition

Comment: What is the exact version of VS (help -> about)?

Comment: Now I see you wrote 16.2.2, I have 16.1.6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> There is no menu to create “new team project” on visual studio 2019

Yes, I could reproduced this issue with Visual Studio 2019 Community 16.2.0 and TFS 2015, 2017, and 2018.

If you connect to a TFS Server 2019 environment, the option will return:

[image]

Then I searched a lot of documents, but I haven't found any explanation for this situation so far. So, I could not sure if this is by designed or it is a issue.

I found someone has already reported this issue to the development team, so I gave a comment with more test info.

Ticket: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/690875/cannot-create-a-new-team-project-from-within-the-t.html

You could vote and add your comments for this feedback track this issue. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

Answer (score 4):

I did a workaroud:
Install minimal VS 2017 Community and create team project from there, then go back to VS 2019 Community.

(VS 2019 Version 16.4.2, after several months the issue is still not fixed)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I installed VS2015 with minimal features and I created the project in that environment. Then I continued the other steps in VS2019.