# Can't create team project in tfs express 2015

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control

I'm using TFS Express 2015 and Visual Studio Community 2019. When I try to add solution to source control, I'm getting an error message: 
"TF206018: The items could not be added to source control because either no team projects have been set up...".
There's no option of adding team project either in Team Explorer in Visual Studio or in TFS Express Admin Console!?
Is it even possible to work with TFS Express on local machine with VS Community?

Comment: Did you start by looking for documentation on how to do this? This question should be easily answered with a Google search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's an existing issue that there is no "New Team Project" option in VS 2019 connecting TFS 2015. Check the following case:

- [There is no menu to create "new team project" on visual studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57501950/there-is-no-menu-to-create-new-team-project-on-visual-studio-2019)

This issue has been reported in the following ticket, please vote and add your comments for this feedback track this issue: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/690875/cannot-create-a-new-team-project-from-within-the-t.html

Since it's supported to [create and delete Team projects from the web experience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/create-project?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) in TFS 2015.2 and later, you need to check your TFS edition to see whether you can create a team project from web protal:

[image]

As a workaround, you may need to use other versions of VS or install high version TFS.

Comment: Are you able to create a team project using the workaround?